# Cross-validation for Ordinary least squares

Tags: cross-validation, least-squares

I want to do a ordinary least-square (OLS) fit to points (no error bars, they are not measurements) to find linear coefficients. I know that the model is imperfect, and want to quantify the model quality by the largest error.

To make this a bit more robust, I thought I would leave some data out (jack-knife, K-fold, or bootstrap), and record the worst prediction error. I know I can do this easily by applying the OLS repeatedly.

Is it possible to simulate the absence of some points without repeatedly performing OLS?

I know it is not possible in general for arbitrary models, but since OLS is so simple, and can be solved with linear algebra, I have this question. An additional driver is that I need to solve this problem many times per second with a quite substantial number of parameters, so fewer matrix decompositions would be helpful.

Comment: I am not sure if you have something like this in mind, but I have seen people plot leverage against the square of the normalized residuals. Observations with high leverage and a smaller-than-average residuals exert a strong influence on the fitted equation. See Samprit Chatterjee. Ali S. Hadi. "Influential Observations, High Leverage Points, and Outliers in Linear Regression." Statist. Sci. 1 (3) 379 - 393, August, 1986. https://doi.org/10.1214/ss/1177013622

Answer (score 0):

In the high-data limit, the average prediction variance is the

(Residual Square Sum) / (number of data) + 2 * (number of parameters)

according to the [Stone (1977)](https://iri.columbia.edu/%7Etippett/cv_papers/Stone1977.pdf) paper which links least squares and the Akaike information criterion.